# Escape extra quotes in malformed xml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I've malformed xml file that contains extra quotes in a tag. I would like to remove them or replace by &quote. 
Malformed XML looks looks like:

```
<CLASS ATT2="PDX"R"088">
```

My expected result:

```
<CLASS ATT2="PDX R 088">
or
<CLASS ATT2="PDX&quot;R&quot;088">
```

I've tried to iterate through all lines and finding ATT first and last indexes but it's quite dirty and produces too much code.

Do anyone have simple solution for this?

Comment: Note that the variant with `&quote` isn't well formed either.

Comment: You mean &quot; ?

Comment: Note that your content is ambiguous so there will never be a 100% perfect solution to this. But you can get some way by noting that the quote delimiters for an attribute value must either be preceded by "=" (perhaps with intervening whitespace), or must be followed by whitespace or ">" or "/>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not 100% foolproof, but might work with a little luck:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!=)"(?!>)', '&quot;', malformed_xml)
```

will only replace quotes that are neither preceded by `=` nor followed by `>`.

If there could be whitespace after `=` (or before `>`), you can't use the `re` module anymore, but the [`regex` module (PyPI)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) can work with this:

```
regex.sub(r'(?<!=\s*)"(?!\s*>)', '&quot;', malformed_xml)
```

Comment: But it's also replacing last one and result looks like: "PDX&quot;R&quot;088&quot;

Comment: It doesn't on your test string: https://regex101.com/r/eSUpsJ/1 - as I said, it only works if there is no whitespace (or anything else) between the quote and the closing angle bracket.

Comment: Could I somehow declare starting string? to only replace quotes in tag ATT2.

Comment: Yes, but only with the regex module: `regex.sub(r'(?<=\bATT2\s*=\s*".*)"(?!\s*>)', '&quot;', malformed_xml)`

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution maybe, but since you cannot parse it with (e.g.) xml.etree as it is invalid, you can try playing with something like the code below.

It will:

1. open the file
2. read it line by line
3. search for each line if there's a specific string (e.g. `CLASS`)
4. if `CLASS` is found, find all the occurrences of double quotes (`"`)
5. check if more than two double-quotes are found and replace them with white space
6. update the lines

**WARNING: BACKUP YOUR ORIGINAL FILE AS THIS WILL MODIFY IT!!!**

```
import re

f = open(r'YOUR/FILE/HERE',"r+b")
lines = f.readlines()
for idx, row in enumerate(lines):
     if "CLASS" in row:
         quote_index = [x.start() for x in re.finditer('\"', row)]
         if len(quote_index) > 2:
             replace_quote = quote_index[1:-1]
             correct_row = list(row)
             for quotes in replace_quote:
                 correct_row[quotes] = " "
             new_row = "".join(correct_row)
             lines[idx] = new_row
f.seek(0)
f.truncate()
f.write(''.join(lines))
f.close()
```